# Regex for String Parse

Tags: python, sql, parsing

I am attempting to build a list of column values and declaration types in Python based on this String, which is an SQL creation query:

```
creation_sql = '''CREATE TABLE "objects_users" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    "clientID" integer NOT NULL, 
    "email" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "first_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "last_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "phone" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "password" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "type" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "date_created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, 
    "active" varchar(100) NOT NULL);'''
```

I have already parsed the quoted values out of the expression like so:

```
def parse(creation_query):

    quoted_values = re.compile('"[^"]*"')
    values = quoted_values.findall(creation_sql)

    column_names = []
    for value in values:
        column_names.append(value)

    table_name = column_names[0]
    column_names = [names.replace('"','') for names in column_names]

    del column_names[0]         # this will be table name
    print(table_name)
    print(column_names)
```

How do I go about parsing the SQL type values from each line?

For example, I have already gathered `id` and `clientID` in a list. Now I want the declaration, `serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` and `integer NOT NULL`, etc... in a list.

How can I accomplish this type of parsing? I dict would be best but I can figure that out on my own, I just need the regex

**Update**

Here is updated code that provides me a dictionary of everything I need based on the creation_sql statement:

```
import re

creation_sql = '''CREATE TABLE "objects_users" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    "clientID" integer NOT NULL, 
    "email" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "first_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "last_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "phone" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "password" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "type" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "date_created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, 
    "active" varchar(100) NOT NULL);'''

def parse(creation_query):

    quoted_values = re.compile('"[^"]*"')
    table_name = quoted_values.findall(creation_query)[0]

    dictionary_values = dict(re.findall('"(.*?)"\s+(.+)[,)]', creation_query))
    dictionary_values['table_name'] = table_name.replace('"','')

    return dictionary_values

d = parse(creation_sql)
print(d.get('table_name'))
for key, item in d.items():
    if key != 'table_name':
        print(key + ":"+ item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
r = re.findall('"(.*?)"\s+(.+)?[,)]', creation_sql)

print(dict(r))
```

Comment: Elegant, I don't even need the initial regex with this, this gives me exactly what I was trying to do in a single step, thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, that regex didn't select the "active" field. `(.*?)"\s+(.+)[,)]` Seems to give me the full dict I needed, although it does match an extra **)** using regex alone

Comment: True I forgot about the last line. Also if there is extra white space or other issues it could cause this regex to fail.